# How to center a word with respect to a paragraph?

Tags: css

Say I have the following text input:

> ```
>  Essen Oxland Road, 34, LS4 7Du      
>  Leeds, United Kingdom
> ```

How can I style to appear as:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` with `vertical-align:middle`

HTML

```
<span class="left">
    Essen
</span>
<span class="right">
    Oxland Road, 34, LS4 7Du<br>
    Leeds, United Kingdom
</span>
```

CSS

```
span.left, span.right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Demo on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ohujip/2/)

Note that `display:inline-block` does not work properly in IE7 and lower.

Comment: but how do I keep all the text centered in the page? float:left takes Essen to the lhs of the page, away from the text-align:center text.

Comment: Thank you. But why is it that i cannot make Essen's font-size:30px? When I do that it goes in line with the second line.

Comment: You need to make sure, that `.left` is exactly as high as `.right`, so when you set `font-size:14px` on `.right`, you need to set `line-height:28px` on `.left`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NRPhC/

Comment: You can also use `display:table-cell` which works even when the number of lines will change. http://jsbin.com/ahiwif

Comment: brilliant! Can set font of left at wish.

Comment: previous was better for margin: 0 auto

Comment: yes, but you can use `text-align:center` again—see the Demo in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.left {
      float:left;
      line-height: 2.0;
      }

    <span class="left">
        Essen
    </span>
    <span>
        Oxland Road, 34, LS4 7Du<br>
        Leeds, United Kingdom
    </span>
```